# Como incluir um trecho de código para ser testado na página do Stack Overflow?

Tags: suporte, stack-snippets

Vejo em algumas perguntas trechos de *códigos* que são *executados* na própria página da pergunta como posso fazer o mesmo?

Comment: @bfavaretto. Obrigado, mas quando eu dei uma pesquisada não tinha nada que se assemelha-se a minha questão, dai o motivo da pergunta!!

Comment: Nao se preocupe, o marcar duplicata nao indica que voce cometeu um erro, ele apenas mescla as perguntas, para que a sua aponte pra respostas ja existentes para novos usuarios que pesquisarem e encontrarem a sua pergunta poderem encontrar as respostas. Digamos que a sua pergunta servira como um apontamento. Veja um exemplo que ocorreu comigo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2600/3635 - Boa note!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela informação @Guilherme Nascimento!